# How do i find duplicate values from two different documents in Notepad++?

Tags: compare, notepad++

So i have 2 files. One contains data in the format of(file 1):

user:pass|IP:PORT|

user:pass|IP:PORT|

....

The other file contains the data(file 2):

IP:PORT

IP:PORT

....

I need to see how many times each of the IP:PORT combination of file 2, appears in file 1.

The results need to be highlighted in file 1, to determine how many times each of the IP:PORT combinations appeared like so:

user:pass|123.123:4444|

user:pass|456.456:4444|

user:pass|123.123:4444|

So from this document, I would receive the info that "123.123:444" appears twice, and "456.456:4444" appears once. But only if they exist in the other document, I compared with.

Comment: This may be tough to achieve using Notepad++ alone.  Do you have any other tools available?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ill use any tool u can recommend, doing it in Notepad++ is not a necessity.

Comment: At first glance, I might read in both sets of data into Java, and then go from there.  Any language would probably do, e.g. also C#, Perl, Python, etc.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way without programming :/

Comment: wrong tool, use a spreadsheet! Open the first file in excel or other spreadsheet tool with `|` as delimiter. Paste the second file in another column, use some of the `countif` or similar functions that are available in spreadsheet tools in a fourth columns. Filter on the fourth column.

Comment: @LarsFischer Thanks Lars! Ill try that out, sounds like it could work!